# What is this prayer with an acrostic in the third letters?

Tags: prayer-book

A friend sent me the following question:

> Many years ago, I was reading a prayer similar to Ashrei, where each line begins with successive letters of the alphabet.  Then, something odd struck me: the first letter of the *third* word in each sentence of that prayer also was larger than the others, and bolded, though not alphabetical from line to line.  When I asked our Rebbi about the prayer, he said that those "extra" letters spelled out the name of the author of that prayer.  I was wondering if you might remember the specific prayer.

What prayer is that, with both first and third letters bolded in *each* line?

Comment: קי''ט?.........

Comment: Alphabetical acrostics and signature acrostics are both pretty common features of liturgical poetry. Are you sure there is  one specific correct answer to this question?

Comment: I only know what he wrote to me. It did not ring a bell.

Comment: start with a machzor and go through piyyutim